# Where does brew get all its binaries from?

Tags: homebrew, binary

Is there some centralized place were people just put their binaries and brew just queries that? Or do people submit their binaries to Brew? If so how do I go about submitting my binaries to brew?

Comment: Consider [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) in addition to Brew as a package manager.